# How to customize WordPress RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, customization, feed

I am about to create a custom RSS feed for my WordPress blog. Although I am pretty unsure of what I am exactly doing.

The feed needs to send following: 
**Featured image** - 600 x 300 px 
**Description** - First 140 characters of the post 
**Link** - Link to the blog post 
**Title** - Title of the blog post

I have followed the guide published by [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/), but sadly it doesn't make me any smarter.

Does anyone have a solution for this? It would be highly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Add custom size image in your theme `functions.php`

```
/** Custom Image Size For RSS Feed */

function custom_image_sizes() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('custom-rss-image', 600, 300, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_sizes');
```

For to limit words you can call the function `wp_trim_words`

The link and Title are most likely within the original Wordpress template you can choose to re-organize it.

And call it within a custom RSS template.

> The Feed templates are located in the /wp-includes/feed-{type}.php files and include formats for rdf, rss, rss2 and atom. They are triggered by feed rewrite rules using a series of actions defined in wp-includes/functions.php and attached using add_action in wp-includes/default-filters.php.

You can lookup the wordpress link.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds